# How start new WPA device from code using any wpa_supplicant interface

Tags: linux, wpa

I need to open new WPA/WPA2 device from linux c code.
Now I create it manualy by using wpa_supplicant

```
wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c connfig.conf -B
```

- How I can to start it from my code (without using system() )?
- What wpa_supplicant interface is intended for this ?

Maybe, do you have any example ?
hanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming wpa_supplicant is already running, it has the "add_interface" command designed to do just that.

If it isn't already running, you will need to run it, either with system or with exec.

Shachar

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use **wpa_cli**.  wpa_cli is text-based frontend program for interacting with wpa_supplicant. Have a look [here](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/8/wpa_cli/) and [here](http://rtl8192cu.googlecode.com/hg-history/bdd3a2265bdd6a92f24cef3d52fa594b2844c9c1/document/wpa_cli_with_wpa_supplicant.pdf).